# Convert array Students to stream<Integer>

Tags: java, java-stream

How convert an array of students to Stream all marks of all students?

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> markAnn = new HashMap<>();
markAnn.put("Physics", List.of(4,4,5));
markAnn.put("Mathematics", List.of(2,3,4));

Map<String, List<Integer>> markKate = new HashMap<>();
markKate.put("Physics", List.of(1,2,3));
markKate.put("Mathematics", List.of(5,5,3));

StudenT[] students = {new StudenT("Ann", markAnn),new StudenT("Kate", markKate)};
```

```
class Lesson6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, List<Integer>> markAnn = new HashMap<>();
        markAnn.put("Physics", List.of(4,4,5));
        markAnn.put("Mathematics", List.of(2,3,4));

        Map<String, List<Integer>> markKate = new HashMap<>();
        markKate.put("Physics", List.of(1,2,3));
        markKate.put("Mathematics", List.of(5,5,3));

        StudenT[] students = {new StudenT("Ann", markAnn),new StudenT("Kate", markKate)};
        Stream<Integer> integerStream = Stream.of(students).map(StudenT::getMarks).flatMap()               

    }
}

class StudenT {

    private String name;
    private Map<String, List<Integer>> marks;

     public StudenT(String name, Map<String, List<Integer>> marks) {
         this.name = name;
         this.marks = marks;
     }

     public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Map<String, List<Integer>> getMarks() {
        return marks;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can `flatMap` twice. The intermediate `flatMap` flattens the stream to `Stream<List<Integer>>` - the scores of all students but grouped by subject.

```
Stream<Integer> integerStream = Arrays.stream(students)
    .flatMap(s -> s.getMarks().values().stream()) // Stream<List<Integer>>
    .flatMap(Collection::stream); // now flatten it again
```

Comment: thanks, it works
Stream<Integer> integerStream = Arrays.stream(students)
                .flatMap(s -> s.getMarks().values().stream())
                .flatMap(Collection::stream);
        integerStream.forEach(x -> System.out.print(x + " "));